# ADF: Sink Directory Ignored in my Data Flow

Tags: azure-data-lake-gen2, azure-data-factory

Anyone had an issue with the Directory setting in the Sink Dataset.  The files are ending up in the locations that only includes the File System value:

[image]

So the files end up in /curated
But should end up in /curated/profiledata

Comment: When I put the full path in the File System then I get a "has an invalid authority" error "DFExecutorUserError"

Comment: Does the folder 'porfiledata' exist or just auto create it? The File path= container / folder / file. You could try to add  dynamic content with two parameters to set folder name/ and filename.

Comment: @LeonYue I have tried both when the directory exists and when it auto creates, both don't work. In Data Flow you can't use the connection parameters, or I don't know how, there are no settings for parameters in source or sink connections.  I've raised a ticket with MS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the File Name Option that you have selected.

"Output to Single File" will honor that dataset file path folder.

But if you are using "As data in column", we start back at the container root in order to allow you to put your files in different multiple folder locations. You can just append your path to the value in the column in a derived column to set your proper path.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I will test this.  Any ideas why the json after a "Copy Data" is UTF-8 BOM encoded?  My Data Flow can't parse the json due to this I think.

Comment: What do you have set as your encoding in your Copy sink dataset?

Comment: The Sink is set to (Default)UTF-8

Comment: I changed all datasets to use iso-8859-1, this worked.  The file in the last sink had an encoding of just utf-8 though not iso-8859-1, but I'm happy with that.